# Jquery - Show/Hide a hidden input form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, show-hide

I'm new to Javascript and trying to understand it better. I have a form which is generated by php, using data from POST. The form has some hidden form fields, which are supposed to be populated with values after validation.

The relevant html code:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="FormProcessor">
<b>Domain Name: </b>
<input type="text" name="MAIN_DOMAINNAME" value="" id="DomainField">
<input type="hidden" name="CONF_FILE" value="" id="ConfFile">
<div id="infomsg">
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready (function()
{
    $('#DomainField').blur(function() {
        var DomField=$("#DomainField");
        var DomText=DomField.val();     
        var fold="/var/lib/bind/db.";
        alert(fold+DomText);
        var ConfFile=$("#ConfFile");
        ConfFile.val(fold+DomText);
        ConfFile.show();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the second `<input>` field to be 'unhidden' when the focus of the previous field is lost. The function gets executed, and the alert is shown.

On checking the source, I can see that it shows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ConfFile" value="/var/lib/bind/db.g.com" name="CONF_FILE" style="display: inline;">
```

So the value is propogated, so I did address the object properly. Why isnt it becoming shown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A hidden input field is supposed to remain hidden.

What I think you want to do is use a normal input field of the type text and hide it using css. Then you are able to show it using jQuery the way you are doing it now.

It should work if you replace your hidden field with:

```
<input type="text" name="CONF_FILE" value="" id="ConfFile" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Shouldnt I be making it `type="text"`?

Answer (score 2):

using `show()` only sets the display property to something visible, but as the input has a type of hidden, it still won't show, you have to actually change the type for that:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#DomainField').on('blur', function() {
        var DomField = $("#DomainField");
        var DomText  = DomField.val();     
        var fold     = "/var/lib/bind/db.";
        var ConfFile = $("#ConfFile");
        ConfFile.val(fold+DomText).prop('type','text');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Droidzone - you have to change the property with `prop()`, `attr()` will not work for this.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code `input type` is hidden and same is not shown even doing `show` forcefully as `hidden` have property to hide existence of control.So you need to change your `input type`.

You can replace your hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="ConfFile" value="/var/lib/bind/db.g.com" name="CONF_FILE" style="display: inline;">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="ConfFile" value="/var/lib/bind/db.g.com" name="CONF_FILE" style="display: none;">
```

or

```
<input type="label" id="ConfFile" value="/var/lib/bind/db.g.com" name="CONF_FILE" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: you can take `input type` `text/label` which can be easily hide and show as per requirement. and `.attr()` is a attribute of control and as per my last comment `hidden` have not property to show then no matter to add `.attr()`.Hope it will clear now

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's an elegant solution. I tried that to hide/show the whole block `<div>` containing multiple elements using `.css("display", "block");`

Answer (score 0):

You should change attribute from `hidden` to `text` before showing:

```
 ConfFile.attr('type', 'text');
 ConfFile.show();
```

Comment: Replace hidden by text from your code :
<input type="text" name="CONF_FILE" value="" id="ConfFile" style="display:none">

Answer (score -1):

use code for hide

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ConfFile').hide();$('#ConfFile').show();
});
```